# SQL datos dentro de datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como hago una consulta para saber cual es el Área padre y que me traiga a sus hijos?

ejm:

- **"Area A"** me trae a **"Area A1"** y **"Area A2".**
- **"Area A1"** me trae a **"Area A1a""**

tenia lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM areas where parent_id = 0
```

que hasta donde tenia entendido, los que tenían parent_id = 0 serian los padres, pero los hijos también pueden ser padres (algo que no esperaba), yo necesitaría saber que áreas tienen hijos. Espero haberme explicado bien.

Estoy usando mySQL

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la declaración de tus tablas así como lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Pues tenia lo siguiente "SELECT * FROM areas where parent_id = 0", que hasta donde tenia entendido, los que tenían parent_id = 0 serian los padres, pero los hijos también pueden ser padres y fue algo que no me di cuenta, yo necesitaría saber que áreas tienen hijos. Espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega tu consulta SQL a tu pregunta

Comment: oh vale. ya quedo editado. Saludos

Comment: Puedes mencionar cual RDBMS estás usando? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostregSQL, etc.

Comment: Listo, ya lo edite.